# Recursively list all directories that contain one or more jpg image files

Tags: shell, files, find

I'm trying to tidy-up my photos which are, for various historic reasons, scattered all over my system. To enable me to make a start on this task, I've been trying to use the command line to construct a list of all directories that contain one or more jpg files.  I'm certain that I don't have to be concerned about looking for other image file formats, but I do have to allow for jpg appearing in upper and lower case.

I'd like each directory name to appear only once in the final list.  To provide an example, if I have the following directories each of which contain one or more jpg or JPG files....

```
~Mike/Pictures
~Mike/Pictures/London/Olympics
~Mike/Pictures/London
~Mike/Pictures/London/Holiday
~Mike/Photos
~Mike/Family History/Swaine
```

I'd like the results to appear with each directory listed only once - irrespective of the number of image files it might contain - preferably sorted and then written to a file

```
~Mike/Family History/Swaine
~Mike/Photos
~Mike/Pictures
~Mike/Pictures/London
~Mike/Pictures/London/Holiday
~Mike/Pictures/London/Olympics
```

My command line skills are just not up to this!  I can use a lot of the simpler forms of single commands, but once they get complex and/or have to be piped things tend to go wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming JPEG image files have the suffix `.jpg` or `.JPG`:

```
find "$HOME" -type f \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.JPG' \) \
    -exec sh -c 'for d; do dirname "$d"; done' sh {} + | sort -u -o jpeg_dirs.txt
```

This relies on you not having funky directory names with newlines in their names.

With GNU `find`:

```
find "$HOME" -type f \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.JPG' \) -printf '%h\n' | sort -u -o jpeg_dirs.txt
```

These `find` commands will find all JPEG images under your home directory and print the names of the directories where they were found.  The `sort -u` will take this list of directory names, sort it, and remove duplicates. The result will be written to the file `jpeg_dirs.txt` in the current directory.

---

Looking back at this in early 2021 (3.3 years later), I cringe a bit because my solution above, albeit not wrong per se, is a bit backward. It also makes the obvious assumption about "nice filenames" (no newlines).

When you're using `find` to search for directories, don't search for regular files as I did above; actually search for directories.  Once we have the directories, we can look in each of them and see if there is a file matching `*.jpg` or `*.JPG` (further filename suffixes are easy to add):

```bash
find "$HOME" -type d -exec bash -O nullglob -O dotglob -O extglob -c '
    for dirpath do
        set -- "$dirpath"/*.@(jpg|JPG)
        [ "$#" -eq 0 ] || printf "%s\n" "$dirpath"
    done' bash {} +
```

This peeks into each directory from your home directory down and tries to expand the globbing pattern `*.@(jpg|JPG)` in each.  This pattern, which also could have been written as two separate patterns, `*.jpg` and `*.JPG`, matches all the files that we're looking for.  If one name matches, we assume that this is a directory that we want to output the name of.  This will give false positives for directories that contain only *sub directories* with these suffixes.

The shell options that we run our internal `bash` script with allow us to match hidden names (`dotglob`), allow the globbing pattern to disappear completely if it doesn't match anything rather than remain unexpanded (`nullglob`), and allow us the use of the `ksh`-inspired extended globbing pattern `@(...|...)`.

Using the `zsh` shell:

```bash
typeset -U list=(~/**/*.(jpg|JPG)(.DN:h))
print -rC1 $list
```

This creates an array variable, `list`, that has the property that it only stores unique elements.  It is initialized to the result of expanding a filename globbing pattern.  The pattern matches all JPEG image files in or below the home directory, and the `:h` at the end removes the actual filename from the generated pathnames.  The `.` makes the pattern only match regular files, and `D` and `N` act like `dotglob` and `nullglob` in `bash`.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way is to list all the `.jpg` files, then strip off the base names of the files (the part after the final slash), and remove duplicates. You can use `sed` to strip the part of each line after the final slash. There's a command to remove duplicates, which is called `uniq`, but it assumes sorted input; if you're need to sort anyway, you can let `sort` do the uniquification.

```
find ~Mike -iname '*.jpg' | sed 's!/[^/]*$!!' | sort -u >directories_with_jpeg_files.txt
```

This assumes that none of the directories or files involved have a newline in their name. File names with newlines do not appear in normal circumstances, but do beware if the file names may have been chosen by a hostile person (e.g. if you're processing files that have been uploaded to a server and the uploader can choose the file name).

If there are directories containing a lot of JPEG files and not many directories containing no JPEG file, this method spends a lot of time reporting then redundant files. There is no way to tell find to shortcut a directory once it's found something in it. But you can restrict find to directories and tell it to search for a JPEG file in each directory. This increases the cost for directories that don't contain JPEG files, however, so it can have poor performance if there are many JPEGless directories.

```
find ~Mike -type d -exec sh -c '
    for d do
      set -- "$d/*.[Jj][Pp][Gg]";
      if [ -e "$1" ]; then printf %s\\n "$d"; fi
    done
' sh {} + | sort -u >directories_with_jpeg_files.txt
```

Alternatively, in zsh, you can use the `**` wildcard to traverse directories recursively, `(#i)` to match the following path component case-insensitively to make the pattern `**/(#i)*.jpg` matching `*.jpg` and `*.JPG` (and `.Jpg` and so on) in a whole directory tree. Add the history modifier `h` in a glob qualifier to extract the directory part. Stuff this into an array variable `dirs=(…)` and extract the unique elements of this array with the `u` parameter expansion flag.

```
set -o extendedglob # for (#i); best in ~/.zshrc
dirs=(~Mike/**/(#i)*.jpg(:h))
print -lr -- ${(u)dirs} >directories_with_jpeg_files.txt
```

The equivalent of the check-per-directory method above is to use the `e` glob qualifier.

```
print -lr ~Mike/**/*(/e\''set -- $REPLY/*.(#i)jpg(N[1]); (($# != 0))'\') >directories_with_jpeg_files.txt
```

Comment: See also `()(($#)) glob(N)` in zsh to test if a glob has any match.

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -iname '*.jpg' -execdir sh -c 'pwd' _ {} + | sort -u > dirs_with_jpegs.txt
```

Ought to work well enough assuming your implementation of `find` supports `-execdir` (it probably does). `-execdir` executes a command in the directory where the found file is. In this case we execute the command `pwd`, which prints the name of the directory. We wrap the command with `sh -c` to strip arguments. (Some (all?) implementations of `find` require the `{}` argument substitution, which would be the list of jpeg files in the current directory. We want to ignore that list and only print the directory.)